# Can I get access to the code of an already executable Python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I run script test.py, for example, and accidentally change the executable file, but the script from this file continues to work.
In the top I can see what executes "python3 test.py" but it is not quite right.
Can I get access to the code that is executed after I changed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way of recover the source code is using the tools [pyrasite](https://github.com/lmacken/pyrasite) and [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html)

**Pyrasite** is used to inject code into Python processes and **inspect** is used to retrieve the source code of modules, classes, methods, functions, tracebacks, frame objects, and code objects.

E.g.
Initial file: foobar.py

```
import time

def test1():
    print "test1"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while (1):
        time.sleep(1)
        test1()
```

Run and modify the file (I changed the printed string by "test2"):

```
$ python foobar.py 
test1
test1
...
```

It still printing `test1` and if you use pyrasite and inspect you can see the source code of the function that it is running.

```
$ pyrasite-shell 6243
Pyrasite Shell 2.0
Connected to 'python foobar.py'
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:08:31) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(DistantInteractiveConsole)

>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getsource(test1)
'def test1():\n\tprint "test1"\n'
```

Also, It works if you deleted the file too.

Comment: your answer is wonderful, I just have a small question, when I try to call inspect(example_function) (yes I'm sorry about this name), the function defined elsewhere is called ('/usr/local/lib/python3.5 dist-packages/pytg/utils.py) and not in the source file, is it possible to do something with it?

Comment: my definition of function @coroutine
def example_function(sender):

Comment: I guess that you should import the module